# Install another operating system on Kindle Paperwhite

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, software

I have a Kindle Paperwhite, but I would like to format it and install some other operating system on it, like Duokan, for example.
Would anyone have a step-by-step tutorial to do this?

Comment: did you find some solution? i need the same

Comment: https://www.todoereaders.com/en/tutorial-install-duokan-on-your-kindle-device.html There were not enmough characters